# Does the BigCommerce API supports CORS?

Tags: javascript, cors, bigcommerce

I want to exchange information with BigCommerce during application installation and send POST request for code from html page.
But I keep getting blocked by CORS: " No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.". And I cannot find anything about it in BigCommerce API documentation.

Do somebody know, is it supported? Is there any way to call BigCommerce api from javascript in browser?

Comment: The fact that you are seeing a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" response for the request you made then you have your answer. No, for that request they do not support CORS. that may be an omission on their part or it many be as intended. This is really a question for bigcommerce tech support rather than for SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do not support CORS. It is very **insecure** to try to call the API from javascript on in the browser directly. This exposes an API token which enables someone to have access to any data in the store available through basic authentication. This would include PII.

If you really need to call info from the API, please use a secure web service that returns very specific values to your script as opposed to calling it directly.

Comment: Hey, I deployed my app with App Engine and I still get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem, I'm using GWT to make the call to my BC API using Basic Authentication

Comment: Why can't the BigCommerce StoreFront APIs be called from a headless frontend? How does one get an XSRF token in a headless environment?