# Cannot authenticate into BigCommerce API because of CORS

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, bigcommerce

I want to make API calls into the BigCommerce API (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api) using the Basic Authentication.

My AJAX call looks like following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://store-zkk8z5i.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + MY_TOKEN,
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    success: function (event) {
        debugger
    },
    error: function (error) {
        debugger
    }
});
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://store-zkk8z5i.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: A wildcard '*'
>   cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the
>   credentials flag is true. Origin
>   'http://store-zkk8z5i.mybigcommerce.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the
>   withCredentials attribute.

I'm pretty sure that my credentials are okay because I get successful responses when I make my requests using cURL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure that my credentials are okay

That's rather beside the point. Look at the error message:

> **A wildcard '*' cannot be used** in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header **when the credentials flag is true**.

Since you are sending credentials, you can't use a wildcard for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

You have to say `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://store-zkk8z5i.mybigcommerce.com` and not `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Comment: To add to this, we don't advise making request to the API directly from the storefront for security reasons:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942220/is-bigcommerce-api-supports-cors

Comment: But I'm never setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to * anywhere. I think the browser is doing that by itself. Is there a way to stop that? I tried setting it to the way you suggested, no difference

Comment: The browser isn't doing it, `store-zkk8z5i.mybigcommerce.com` is. It is an HTTP response header. If you aren't in control of `store-zkk8z5i.mybigcommerce.com` then you need to either (a) ask whomever does to change it or (b) find some documentation which explains how to use their API without setting `withCredentials: true` … but given Alyss's comment neither of those seem likely, so you should probably switch to making the HTTP request from your server.

Comment: Where to add this. You should show properly.

Comment: @DebduttaPanda — In whatever place you currently say `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`