# Getting 401 error while calling BigCommerce API through AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, e-commerce, bigcommerce

We want to achieve Minimum Purchase Quantity on quick search results by calling API through jQuery/AJAX. We are trying to call the API but not getting the response. We are getting following error message:

> NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized - https://mystore.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/product_id

Following is the code, which we have added in quicksearch.js file.

```
var key = 'API key';
var auth = 'Basic ' + btoa('username:'+key);
var url = 'https://mystore.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/product_id';

$.ajax({
    url : url,
    method : 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend : function(req) {
        req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
    },
    success: function(result) {
        alert('done');
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Can anyone guide to solve the error?

Comment: Your auth token is not recognised by the API. You need to check the you are both generating and passing it correctly.

Comment: You should also remove `async: false`, as it's *incredibly* bad practice.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. Thank you. I have removed "async : false" and also rechecked Auth.  Still getting the same error. Description of 401 error is :- "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://store-zxu7pi.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/86. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)". Can you please guide further ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create separate PHP Application on live server to call the Big-commerce API.

You can create your Legacy API Account from BigCommerce Store - Admin Panel -> Advanced Settings -> Legacy API Settings and can get API url, username, token.

You can implement following code to get the Minimum Purchase Quantity.

file name is getproductinfo.php.

```
    <?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');

    $product_id = $_GET['prod_id'];

    $username='username';
    $password='API token';
    $URL='https://mystoreurl.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/'.$product_id;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:UTF-8','Accept: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch); 


    $data = json_decode($result,true);
    $minimimOrder = $data['order_quantity_minimum'];
    echo $minimimOrder;die();

    ?>
```

The response(Minimum Purchase Quantity)--> you can get in quicksearch.js file using following code as a **result**.

```
 var url = 'http://liveserveripaddress/foldername/getproductinfo.php';
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type : 'GET',
            data : {prod_id:productid},
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,

            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                },
            error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(request.responseText);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Legacy Auth is being deprecated over the new OAuth implementation for BC API's

Comment: I have same issue in one page using api using ajax in console  gettting errorRequest Failed: error, quick-order:666:5
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/j4ip6cs857/v2/products.json?sku=1461-78. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).[Learn More]
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/j4ip6cs857/v2/products.json?sku=1461-78. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Comment: Legacy API Settings and can get API url, username, token not created in demo store??

Answer (score 2):

We do not support CORS. It is very insecure to try to call the API from javascript on in the browser directly. This exposes an API token which enables someone to have access to any data in the store available through basic authentication. This would include PII.

If you really need to call info from the API, please use a secure web service that returns very specific values to your script as opposed to calling it directly.

[Is BigCommerce API supports CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942220/is-bigcommerce-api-supports-cors)

Comment: Thank you @Alyss. This helped :)