# Failed to connect GWT to BigCommerce API

Tags: gwt, cross-domain, bigcommerce, same-origin-policy

**Criteria:** I'm trying to connect to a secured web service API called BigCommerce using GWT RequestBuilder.
This is my entry point:

```
public class GwtTest implements EntryPoint {
    String url = "http://my-url-api/api/v2/products.xml"; // not the original url i'm using

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        url = URL.encode(url);
        RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);
        builder.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic XXX"); // I generated this from Postman app on Chrome where things work perfectly
        builder.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        builder.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://127.0.0.1:8888/");
        builder.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, UPDATE, OPTIONS");
        builder.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-http-method-override");
        builder.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        try {
            builder.sendRequest(url, new RequestCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                    RootPanel.get().add(new HTML("Success: "+response.getText()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                    RootPanel.get().add(new HTML("Failure (Response Error): "+exception));  
                }
            });
        } catch (RequestException e) {
            RootPanel.get().add(new HTML("Failure Request Exception: "+e));
        }
    }
}
```

**Errors encountered:** I encounter the Same Origin Policy error at first:

[image]

Then After I disabled CORS on my browser I get the Perflight error:

[image]

**Work-around:** I was able to get results by disabling web security on Chrome but I don't think it's the right solution.

**Trivial note:** Please guide me on this one, guys, because I'm new to GWT and BigCommerce thanks.

Comment: This seems like a non GWT related issue, but more about how their API is designed. I think your solution here is to connect your GWT app to a backend that will call the API. For more info, you can checkout the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942220/does-the-bigcommerce-api-supports-cors

Comment: You can also use ngrok to run it through. It is recommended under the tools section on the site. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#tools-for-debugging-and-testing-webhooks

Answer (score 1):

Use a proxy servlet.

This is also the solution the GWT Openlayers wrappers uses.

https://github.com/geosdi/GWT-OpenLayers/blob/c3becee0cdd5eefdc40b18e4999c2744dc23363a/gwt-openlayers-server/src/main/java/org/gwtopenmaps/openlayers/server/GwtOpenLayersProxyServlet.java

Comment: how do I run this servlet on my project? I'm totally new with this but i have to make it work

Answer (score 1):

Based on Rob Newton answer, if your application is pure front end, you can host your files on nginx and add some proxy_pass directive to your configuration, for example:

```
location ~* ^/bigcommerce/(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://api.bigcommerce.com/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

So whenever you call `http://hostaddress/bigcommerce/something`, this will be forwared to  `http://api.bigcommerce.com/something`. Headers are not forwared in this config, you can add more directives for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could include a servlet in your webapp that acts as a proxy between the client and BigCommerce.

An alternative is to run a reverse proxy such as Apache httpd that makes requests to the BigCommerce server appear to be on the same host as your webapp.

Here is an example of an Apache httpd config file that will act as a reverse proxy for your webapp and an external service on a different host.  To the browser both the webapp and the external service will appear to be running on the same host, which is what your want.

```
# file: /etc/httpd/conf.d/mywebapp.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  # Forward requests to path /SomeExternalService to an external service
  ProxyPass /SomeExternalService http://externalhost/
  # Forward all other requests to a local webserver hosting your webapp,
  # such as Tomcat listening on port 8081
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you give me an example please