# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present error using bigcommerce api mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, jqgrid, bigcommerce

I am using big commerce API to get orders list , i have tried a lot of solutions.

Here is error which I am facing ..

> api.bigcommerce.com/stores/4jwabif3gj/v2/orders.json?search=false&nd=1541740677952&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) Index:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/4jwabif3gj/v2/orders.json?search=false&nd=1541740677952&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc' from origin 'http://localhost:62797' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**HTML**

```
<table id="JqGrid"></table>
<div id="JqGridPager"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var $grid = $("#JqGrid");
        $grid.jqGrid({
            url: 'https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/4jwabif3gj/v2/orders.json',
            ajaxGridOptions: { xhrFields: { withCredentials: true } }, 
            dataType: 'json',
            colNames: ['id', 'date_created', 'date_modified', 'date_shipped', 'status'],

            colModel: [
                { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 10 },
                { name: 'date_created', index: 'date_created', width: 50, sorttype: 'date', datefmt: 'Y-m-d' },
                { name: 'date_modified', index: 'date_modified', width: 50, sorttype: 'date', datefmt: 'Y-m-d' },
                { name: 'date_shipped', index: 'date_shipped', width: 50, sorttype: 'date', datefmt: 'Y-m-d' },
                { name: 'status', index: 'status', width: 50 },
            ],
            caption: "Order list",
            pager: "#JqGridPager",
            loadBeforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token", 'modebafppdxh9sd90zffehu9wwgpj3d', "X-Auth-Client", '535bnhhfkqblu7ebg1aq9r6kue1lgv6');
            },
            //ajaxGridOptions: {

            //    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            //        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token", "modebafppdxh9sd90zffehu9wwgpj3d", "X-Auth-Client", "535bnhhfkqblu7ebg1aq9r6kue1lgv6");

            //    }
            //},
            viewrecords: true,
            width: 1100,
            height: 400
        });
        $grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#JqGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I need your help about this problem. @Alyss

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35942398/5573177) on StackOverflow and [this thread](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/question/0D51B00003vy3GUSAY/bigcommerce-api-call-using-oauth-token-within-ajax-request) on the BigCommerce support forum, the BigCommerce API does not support CORS. This seems to be a security concern, and making API requests from the client-side is generally discouraged.

The recommended way to access information from the BigCommerce API is to make the calls to the API via from a secure third party server, and to then query this third party server from your web application.

Comment: i also use this method not working in my case.@
Phillip van Heerden

Comment: @user2697533 You should also omit details like API keys (`X-Auth-Token` and `X-Auth-Client`, in your case) from your StackOverflow questions. This information is sensitive, and can allow third parties to access your resources.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the information you are trying to access you can either use the Server to Server request or the Storefront APIs.

Based on your use case the Server to Server API's would be best. There is an overview of the differences between each in the [documentation](https://developer-beta.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/cart-and-checkout/cart-and-checkout-overview). This should help you decide which one is better for your application.

To just return a list of orders you can use this API endpoint [here](https://developer-beta.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/orders-api/orders/getordersid). To capture Order data on the storefront you can use this endpoint [here](https://developer-beta.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/storefront-orders-api).

Comment: ok . I request you can you just do a sample of my code what I change in my code . I will be thankful to you .. I want to get idea that's all I am understanding from What I change in my javascript code.  @T.J.

Comment: i have only this error problem : api.bigcommerce.com/stores/4jwabif3gj/v2/orders?_search=false&nd=1541789295943&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
Index:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/4jwabif3gj/v2/orders?_search=false&nd=1541789295943&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc' from origin 'http://localhost:62797' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.@T.J.

Comment: can you tell me any solution how to resolve this error i am also puth x-Auth-Token and X-Auth-Client , but when i run application this error i am facing . when i click this link show me this line: X-Auth-Client and X-Auth-Token headers are required@T.J.